# Environment variable in GNOME, Scientific Linux 6.1

Tags: bash, environment-variables, gnome

I am using Scientific Linux 6.1. To run a program (DS9) I need to set this environment variable:

```
export XPA_METHOD=local
```

So I saved it in .bashrc and there is no problem when I run the program from the bash terminal. But when I run it in the GUI (for example by clicking on "Open with ds9" in nautilus), this variable is not recognized.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me in setting the environment variable in GNOME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it to ~/.profile instead of .bashrc

**Edit**: Log off and on again for the change to take effect.

Comment: In Scientific Linux 6.1 (based on Enterprise Linux) there is no ~/.profile !!! the only hidden entry with the name including "profile" is ~/.bash_profile which I have also added this line to but has not worked. Which other hidden file controls the environment variables of GNOME? There is ~/.gnome2 directory but I couldn't figure out which of its contents satisfy my need?!?!

Comment: You can create the ~/.profile file. The ~/.bashrc file is only sourced in interactive bash shells. According to this page ~/.profile is not going to help you anyways: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles

Comment: You were right, I created it with only this line and it didn't work!

Comment: You have to log off and on before .profile is sourced again. But if there is a .bash_profile, maybe bash never reads .profile (really, how broken is that?). There is also .pam_environment, but there you don't need the `export` command in the beginning. I don't know, it works on GNOME on FreeBSD

Comment: I am new to Linux so please excuse me of this illiteracy! You were right, after a restart it worked successfully. Thank you so much.